# Hard Disk Partitioning during 12.04 Install

Tags: installation, boot, partitioning, disk, boot-partition

Attempting to install 12.04 LTS on the following system:

> Mainboard: MSI K7T Turbo (MS-6330 v3.0) VIA KT133A 
>   Chipset Processor: AMD Athlon 1300 Mhz
>  
>   HDD: WD EIDE 160Gb LBA Single partition 
>   Memory: 512 MB PC133
>   Current OS: Windows 2000 SP4

I have also created a CD (vs DVD) using the Infra Recorder S/W as recommended by the [Ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com). CD was created without incident. No indication of insufficient space on CD for the Ubuntu installation files. Current size - 729,067,520 bytes CDFS.

**PROBLEM**: The partitioning of the hard disk stalls. It does not appear to detect the existing HDD and partition. Additionally, the installation does not present options for creating/modifying the partition and just hangs.

NEXT:

- I am going to delete the existing partition and either

  1) have unpartitioned media ready for install; or

  2) delete existing and re-create partition either formatted or non-formatted ready for install.
- I am going to create an installation DVD (vs.CD) per recommendation to see if this makes a difference.

Is there a limit to the HDD size for Ubuntu install or is the hardware just too old?

Answer (score 0):

Try switch the SATA mode in the BIOS from IDE to AHCI. You can plug HDD to another connector on the motherboard. And try this `sudo fdisk -l` under installation in terminal.